# Monitoring XHR requests on Chrome in Linux

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Is there a way to monitor AJAX requests in the Chrome browser?  I tried firebug lite, and though it seems to work for some things (javascript errors and such), the XHR tab doesn't seem to do anything.

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome ships with developer tools similar to firebug.  Look for "Developer" in the chrome menu.  XHR logging would be under the resources tab.

Comment: I could have sworn I've looked in there a bunch of times for it.